# Merge two dictionaries and remove duplicate keys and sort by the value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have to merge two dictionaries into one dictionary with removing duplicate entries and add if not present in the first dictionary.

```
 Dictionary<int, string> firstDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 firstDict.Add(1, "X");
 firstDict.Add(2, "B");

 Dictionary<int, string> secondDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 secondDict.Add(1, "M");
 secondDict.Add(4, "A");
```

Result Should be like this:

```
{4, "A"}
{2, "B"}
{1, "X"}
```

Comment: Dictionary won't allow you to add duplicate keys by default.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I have edited the question. Basically I want to merge dictionaries (without having duplicate entries) and if key not present in the first dictionary then add item from second dictionary to first dictionary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Concat with sample LINQ to achieve what you want. Here it is:

```
Dictionary<int, string> result = 
   firstDict.Concat(secondDict.Where(kvp => !firstDict.ContainsKey(kvp.Key)))
            .OrderBy(c=>c.Value)
            .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value);
```

The result is:

```
{4, "A"}
{2, "B"}
{1, "X"}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is only one line answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (var item in firstDict)
{
    secondDict[item.Key] = item.Value;
}
```

**Update:**

If you want to preserve initial values, make a copy of secondDict:

```
Dictionary<int, string> resultDict = new Dictionary<int, string>(secondDict);
foreach (var item in firstDict)
{
    resultDict[item.Key] = item.Value;
}
```

Comment: The original post preserves the existing value.

Answer (score 1):

You would do something like this:

```
var result = firstDict;
foreach(var newitem in secondDict.Where(x => !firstDict.ContainsKey(x.Key)))
    result.Add(newItem);

var sortedResult = result.OrderBy(x => x.Value);
```

Please note that `result` is still a dictionary but unsorted while `sortedResult` is sorted but no longer a dictionary, because the order of items in a dictionary is undefined. You can't use [`SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) either, because it is sorted by the key and not the value.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach (int key in secondDict.Keys)
{
    if (!firstDict.ContainsKey(key))
    firstDict.Add(key, secondDict[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
foreach(var pair in secondDict)
{
   if(!(firstDict.ContainsKey(pair.Key)))
   {
      firstDict.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);
   }
}
```

Is this what you want? I haven´t tested it yet by compiler, so give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, do you want to merge both of them?
If so, can you just:

1st. Create a copy of the firstDict where the final results will be set.

2nd. For each key in secondDict:

```
1. Check if key exists in firstDict.

1.1. If it does exist(we want to keep the current result): do not do anything(sorry I miss read the result earlier)

1.2. If it doesn't exist then insert it as is(key-value from secondDict into firstDict)
```

Hopefully it helps!

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to let C# do the work.

```
return firstDict.ToList().Union(SecondDict.ToList()).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

and if you can, change the return to IEnumerable, and remove ToDictioary.

```
return firstDict.ToList().Union(SecondDict.ToList());
```